# HttpHandler accessing same session

Tags: session, httphandler

I'm using a `HttpHandler` to upload an image asynchronously and need access to the **SAME** session as the rest of the application.

I'm using `IRequiresSessionState` and can read and write to the session fine, but existing session values from the application that should be available aren't and so on.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: How do you upload your image? If you use SWFUpload and another browser than IE, you might have come across the infamous session-bug where flash uses an instance of IE for the http-request (meaning, a whole other session)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using.  I take it that means I'm screwed?